# Прочитать число из шифра

Tags: python

На вход всегда подаются только 4 строки - это графический образ зашифрованного числа, каждая цифра которого изображена символами ('#' и '.') одной из представленных ниже матриц:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, если на вход поданы такие 4 строки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] ,

то на выход нужно подать одну строку с числом 79098654321.

Итак, в данной задаче на выход нужно подать число, распознанное из графического образа. Число может быть в диапазоне [0; 1000000000000].

```
sp = [['##','##','##','##'],
      ['.#','##','.#','.#'],
      ['##','.#','#.','##'],
      ['##','.#','.#','##'],
      ['##','##','.#','.#'],
      ['##','#.','.#','##'],
      ['.#','#.','##','##'],
      ['##','.#','#.','#.'],
      ['##','..','##','##'],
      ['##','##','.#','#.']]
tmp = []
text = []
for i in range(4):
    text = input()
    tmp.append([text[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(text), 2)])
```

Начал так, закончить не могу. Подскажите пожалуйсто. Не могу понять как входящие данные выстроить в нужном порядке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например можно такой код сделать:

```
text = ['.###', '##.#', '.##.', '.##.'] # пример числа 17

dictionary = ['########', '.###.#.#', '##.##.##', '##.#.###', '####.#.#', '###..###', '.##.####', '##.##.#.', '##..####', '####.##.']

res = ''

for i in range(0, len(text[0]), 2):
    figure = text[0][i:i+2] + text[1][i:i+2] + text[2][i:i+2] + text[3][i:i+2]

    if figure not in dictionary:
        res += '*'
    else:
        res += str(dictionary.index(figure))

print(res)
```

в переменную `text` я занес 2 числа, но если надо запросить с клавиатуры, то надо сделать так:

```
text = [input(), input(), input(), input()]
```

Ну и если есть желание сделать все в 1 строку:

```
res = ''.join(str(dictionary.index(''.join(text[j][i:i+2] for j in range(4)))) if ''.join(text[j][i:i+2] for j in range(4)) in dictionary else '*' for i in range(0, len(text[0]), 2))
```

А если гарантированно нет левых символов вне словаря (которые заменяются у меня на `'*'`), то код можно еще упростить:

```
res = ''.join(str(dictionary.index(''.join(text[j][i:i+2] for j in range(4)))) for i in range(0, len(text[0]), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

у меня так получилось, вроде работает, попробуйте:

```
sp = [['##','##','##','##'],
      ['.#','##','.#','.#'],
      ['##','.#','#.','##'],
      ['##','.#','.#','##'],
      ['##','##','.#','.#'],
      ['##','#.','.#','##'],
      ['.#','#.','##','##'],
      ['##','.#','#.','#.'],
      ['##','..','##','##'],
      ['##','##','.#','#.']]

text = ['##########', 
        '.#######..', 
        '#..###.###', 
        '#.#.###.##']

from textwrap import wrap

w = [wrap(i,2) for i in text]
res = ''.join(str(sp.index(list(j))) for j in zip(*w))  # '79098'
```